# How to trigger TS.43 entitlement flow with ImsServiceEntitlement app

Tags: java, android, telecommunication

I have a back end application which is supposed to work as Entitlement server in TS.43 flow ( https://www.gsma.com/newsroom/wp-content/uploads//TS.43-v8.0-3.pdf ). I want to test this application by triggering TS.43 flow on my android device. I have tried to do it with the help of the following documentation:
https://source.android.com/docs/core/connect/ims-service-entitlement#entitlement-app

How should I trigger this application to start TS.43 flow entitlement?
I know about the need to change the url through Carrier Config, but for purposes of this discussion I am interested in how to just trigger this flow, so that the requests are made.

What I have found:
I have found the source code: https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:packages/apps/ImsServiceEntitlement/
However I couldn't find some Readme.md file explaining how to trigger requests from this application.

Details of test device:

Android 12, Samsung Galaxy A52